# View physical size before placing component, DipTrace

Tags: pcb-design, components, diptrace

Is there a way to view the physical size of a component before it is placed in the schematic editor in DipTrace, like it's shown in Eagle?

I like to use DipTrace because it seem to have a nice autorouter with automatic component placement. But, it seems more difficult to add components if you don't know the exact package name in DipTrace.

Comment: Sorry, I never even heard of DipTrace.  However, the EAGLE tag seem inappropriate since you're not asking about that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Although I'm not asking about EAGLE, I'm asking if there is a feature in the other software similar to one in EAGLE. Don't the tag apply then?

Comment: I think it wouldn't.

Comment: Autorouter (particularly if you're using autoplacement too) = A Bad Idea probably ~99% of the time.

Comment: Autorouters are easily confused when you have mixed analog and digital signals with separate "star" topologies for power and ground distribution. Orcad with specctra  is good for autorouting data/address busses as you can group them by flight-time or other important parameters. Though I mentioned Orcad because I use it, all autorouters have the above issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that i know of is to drag the part into your schematic, then go: right click -> properties -> attached pattern -> check pattern dimensions. You can also see a preview in the bottom left hand corner when the part is selected before you add it.

[image]

Adding then deleting a part like this shouldn't cause any issues.

Also don't forget that parts and footprints are only loosely linked. You can always just make your schematic using generic symbols; Then before you start creating your PCB you can go through and set/change the footprints to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use auto-routing/auto-placement. Although Diptrace is good at both, you should not use them if you want to design     a efficient PCB layout.
In allegro there is a option called PLACE BOUND TOP where you can specify the physical height of the component.